# D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain Software parameter

Tags: c, directx-11

```
HRESULT D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
  _In_   IDXGIAdapter *pAdapter,
  _In_   D3D_DRIVER_TYPE DriverType,
  _In_   HMODULE Software,                  //<-- This parameter
  _In_   UINT Flags,
  _In_   const D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL *pFeatureLevels,
  _In_   UINT FeatureLevels,
  _In_   UINT SDKVersion,
  _In_   const DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC *pSwapChainDesc,
  _Out_  IDXGISwapChain **ppSwapChain,
  _Out_  ID3D11Device **ppDevice,
  _Out_  D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL *pFeatureLevel,
  _Out_  ID3D11DeviceContext **ppImmediateContext
);
```

Someone knows an example on how use this parameter, with WARP by example.

Comment: From [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476083%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it says

A handle to a DLL that implements a software rasterizer. If DriverType is D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, Software must not be NULL. Get the handle by calling LoadLibrary, LoadLibraryEx , or GetModuleHandle. The value should be non-NULL when D3D_DRIVER_TYPE is D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_SOFTWARE and NULL otherwise.

Comment: I know that documentation, I'm looking for an usage example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform such a task would require you to write or use a custom software rasterizer, meaning you would need to implement the entire D3D driver implementation and emulate the physical device.  Then D3D will forward all API calls to this module for execution.  The code would look very similar to the following:

```
static const D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL levels[] = {
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,  
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1
};

uint32_t flags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT; 

#ifdef _DEBUG
flags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Device> device = nullptr;
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> deviceContext = nullptr;
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain> swapChain = nullptr;
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL selectedFeatureLevel;

DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swap_chain_props { };
swap_chain_props.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
swap_chain_props.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL;
swap_chain_props.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
swap_chain_props.BufferCount = 2;

HMODULE custom_raterizer = ::LoadLibrary(L"X:\\FolderName\\CustomRasterizer.dll");

HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(nullptr, 
                                           D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, 
                                           custom_raterizer, 
                                           flags, 
                                           levels, 
                                           ARRAYSIZE(levels), 
                                           D3D11_SDK_VERSION, 
                                           &swap_chain_props,
                                           swapChain.GetAddressOf(),
                                           device.GetAddressOf(), 
                                           &selectedFeatureLevel, 
                                           deviceContext.GetAddressOf());
```

However, this would be a very large undertaking.  WARP performs extremely well for a software rasterizer, allowing you to pass D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP for the driver type, and nullptr for the module handle.  Take a peek [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg615082(v=vs.85).aspx) in the section [Removing the Need for Custom Software Rasterizers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg615082(v=vs.85).aspx#removing_the_need_for_custom_software_rasterizers).

On the other hand, to your point, I wish the WARP driver was open source.  I would love to play around with it using the above code!

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

I did stumble across [this link](http://www.irrlicht3d.org/pivot/entry.php?id=185) which appear to have a open source 3D software rasterizer.  Keep in mind, it would have to be completely compatible and stable with your target feature level (D3D version).